# "Cannot find symbol"-error with custom class

Tags: java

I have got this simple method written in a custom class `Numbers.java`:

```
public class Numbers {
    public int add (int n,int m) {
        int i = n + m;
        return i;
    }
}
```

But when I try to call this method in my `main`-class like so:

```
private void btnAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    int i = add(4, 6);
}
```

I get an red error sign on the line number of `int i = add(4, 6);` saying:

```
 cannot find symbol
   symbol: method add(int,int)
   location: class Main
```

Also, when I wrote the method in my custom class I got a yellow warning sign on the line number where I declared the method saying "Missing Javadoc". I did some googling on this and found out that you were supposed to add certain URL's to your Java Platform Manager under the tab Javadoc, but as far as I can see all of my URL's are in place. I include a picture of it down below:

[image]

I have no idea what is wrong, and I'm grateful for any help!

Comment: what is `i` in `add()`?

Comment: @rakeb.void Sorry, should be `int i`, fixed it!

Comment: What is `tal`? Could you post the full problematic code? What is the context where you invoke `btnAddtionPerformed` method?

Comment: Is a class `Main` the same package as `Numbers`?

Comment: @Xeon Sorry, forgot to translate `tal` to `add`. It's the same method!

Comment: @RomanC Yes that is correct!

Comment: @majesticUnicorn I'm quite sure it'll work though: `int i = new Numbers().add(4, 6)`. And you're probably in wrong scope.

Comment: @majesticUnicorn You can't just call a method from different class without a class reference.

Comment: @Xeon @ Roman C Thank you very much for you help! I'm going to study classes and scope a little more!

Comment: @majesticUnicorn Next time you prepare for the question before asking it on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method `btnAddActionPerformed` is in class `Main`, and is trying to call a function `add`, which is in a different class.  Try this:

```
public class Numbers {
    public static int add (int n,int m) {
        int i = n + m;
        return i;
    }
}
```

And:

```
private void btnAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    int i = Numbers.add(4, 6);
}
```